# How to run all test files from separate folders - jest

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, nest

I am able to test each file using Jest, but I cannot figure out how to test multiple test files from separate folders.
I have a folder named test and it has 2 sub folders: e2e and unit.
I have these scripts to run these tests individually:

```
"test": "jest",
"test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/e2e/jest-e2e.json",
"test:unit": "jest --config ./test/unit/jest-unit.json"
```

When I run `npm test` it only runs the `spec` file inside the `src` directory.
Also other 2 scripts runs the tests inside e2e and unit respectively.

Is there a way to run all of these tests with one script only?

Comment: Show your jest config and how the test files are named.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the folder name to `__tests__` or add a `jest.config.js` at the repo root with a [`testMatch`](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testmatch-arraystring) like this

```js
testMatch: [
  '**/test/**/*.js'
]
```